# Which is best for built a web tool in gwt

Tags: gwt, liquid-layout

I am new to GWT. can anyone help me to understand which one is best to built a web tool. Fluid Layout or Fixed layout...?

help me in this...

Thanks,,

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the application you want to create.
I would always go for the flexible layout, if there a no contrary requirements.